# Disabling one Spinner when a certain value is selected from another spinner

Tags: android

I have two spinner in a Single activity one of the spinner is populating values from the Database and the other one has static values.

When a user Select a certain value like "Store" from the static spinner The application should should disable the dynamic spinner and when a user selects in use it should enable the spinner. How can i do this.

This is how my Static Spinner code looks like

```
 public void addStatus()
    {

        statusspinner =(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Statusofasset);

        // creating a array list and populating the spinner which static values
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("In Storage");
        list.add("In Use");
        // Creating adapter for spinner
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
        // Drop down layout style
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        //Assigning the adapter to the spinner
        statusspinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);


    }
```

And the Dynamic Spinner is show below.

```
public void SelectedCustodianValues()
    {

        List<String> CustodianIds =  handler.getAllNames();

        // Creating adapter for spinner
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, CustodianIds);

        // Drop down layout style
        dataAdapter .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        // attaching data adapter to spinner
        CustodianSpinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

    }
```

Comment: You can do that on selection of value of a spinner and probably use `setEnabled(boolean)` for the second spinner

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setEnabled();` method for doing this.

```
enableDesableSpinner()
{
   staticspinner=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.staticspinner);
   DBspinner=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.DBspinner);
   String text = staticspinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
   if(text=="Store");
   {
     DBspinner.setEnabled(false);
   }
   else
   {
     DBspinner.setEnabled(true);
   }
}
```

Comment: I did try the method u have mentioned but the spinner does not get enabled when i have selected another value other than Store.

Comment: how did you call `enableDesableSpinner()` method?

Comment: Well i have called the method in the onCreate method  like so

`protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_issuean_asset);`
    
 enableDesableSpinner();

   }`

Comment: Call it on spinner on change.

Comment: tried call in the method on  `public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
       enableDesableSpinner();
    }`

But the activity crashes could you post a snippet of how i can do this